# C++: How do you set up an if-else statement for a return function

Tags: c++

I am doing this for a math class and just cannot get the if-else statement to work. Can someone tell me what I should do for the else statement? My idea is to pass a vector into a function and every time the function sees "close" it changes it to "open" and vice versa. The compiler always stops at the if statement, that is nothing after the first element in the vector gets changed :

```
string getValue(vector<string> &arr)
{

    for(int i=2; i <=50; i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]=="close")
        {
          return arr[i]="open";
        }
    }

    return "close";

}
```

Comment: I would switch out that loop for `std::find`.

Comment: You should probably be checking against the size of the vector in your for-loop so that you don't run into segfaults

Comment: Why do you have a `return` statement in the middle of the loop?

Comment: What debugging methods have you tried so far?

Comment: I have no segfaults and I've already used .push_back() in main().

Comment: as Jerry Coffin said you returned from the function, the time it got true.

Comment: Not very professional, but I would just make a boolean variable and that loop will set it to true if "close" exists and break the loop with break; Then, make an if statement returning whatever value you want. I dont 100% understand this question, but that's what I would do.

Comment: I think I sort of get what you're actually trying to do now. In that case, `std::transform` or a short ranged-for would be better.

Comment: I still don't understand what the OP is trying to *do*. An example vector of 3 or 4 mixed values (close, open, close, open) and what expectations are when finished would probably speak thunderous volumes for the actual *problem*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `return`. The first time the `if` statement is true, the `return` statement executes, returning from the current function. Presumably, you intended it to just be `array[i] = "open";`

As far as the `else` goes, from your description you want something like:

```
else if (array[i] == "open")
    array[i] = "close";
```

Personally, I think I'd change it to use numbers instead, with the associated strings stored separately:

```
enum { OPEN, CLOSE };
static const int names[] = {"open", "close"};
```

Then you can convert `OPEN` to `CLOSE` and vice versa with something like:

```
for (int &i : arr)
    i = 1 - i;
```

Comment: @greatwolf: Maybe. There are all sorts of possibilities, but none that jumps out as obviously better than the rest.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
void getValue(vector<string> &arr)
{
    for(int i=0; i <arr.size(); i++)
    {
        if(arr[i]=="close")
        {
          arr[i]="open";
        }
        else if(arr[i]=="open")
        {
          arr[i]="close";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the OP only wants the *first*  encountered `"open"` to be changed to `"close"`. Hard saying at this point.

Comment: @WhozCraig, OP complains that "nothing after the first element in the vector gets changed"

Comment: He also says he wants to replace `"open"` with `"close"`, which `std::replace` won't support (without extra work).

Comment: @JerryCoffin so they basically want a sweeping bit-toggle, is that about right?

Comment: Why do we even need to guess what the OP is trying to do? I don't think we downvoted him enough.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Yes, I think so.